# Create Notification with Custom Button Component

Tags: android, push-notification, components, radix

I have to design a notification with custom layout and component such as button and textview which is written as a base component. I handled the custom view side with RemoteView. I have created custom layout and in this layout, I created Textview and Button. 
The problem is that I have to use button and textview from base component which was written previously in my framework but when I try to use it, it gives an error.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.n9020732.remoteview, PID: 2945
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.example.n9020732.remoteview: Couldn't inflate contentViewsandroid.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class com.example.n9020732.remoteview.AXButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I create notification in this Service.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d("ONMESSAGERECEIVED", "Heloo");

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

        RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.remote_view);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentText("Content of the notification")
                .setContentTitle("Title of the notification:")
                .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);

        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
}
```

}

This is the base component.

```
public class AButton extends 
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{
public AButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public AButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}
```

remote_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Description"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bas bana!"/>

    <com.example.n9020732.remoteview.AXButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Basma!"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i use my base component in the notification.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: That was the only code I wrote. This is for trying to figure out using Custom Component in basic project. After that, I will add it to real project.